# How can I say that something asks for more problems?

Tags: word-request

Is there a very known way to say that something asks for more problems? In other words, that a new solution, for example, is very likely to cause more problems than solve.

Comment: Do you mean more common than "This will cause more problems than it solves" - which is a nice natural sounding and idiomatic expression

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'm complicating it.

Comment: @JamesK You should make that an answer.

Comment: You're [*asking for **trouble***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/asking-for-trouble) if you're *behaving in a way that is likely to cause **problems / a problem** for you*. But idiomatically, we simply don't normally say you're *asking for **problems*** if you're *behaving in a way that is likely to cause **trouble[s]** for you*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a colorful idiom for a solution that introduces problematic complexities: it "[opens up a can of worms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open%20a%20can%20of%20worms)."

Comment: I've also heard "open a new can of worms" or "open a fresh can of worms" for the implication that there's already been a lot of such complications on a project.

Comment: This expression means "it creates unanticipated problems". It has no suggestion of anything working against the intended purpose.

Answer (score 5):

> "*This **invites** (more) problems (than it solves)*"

is an idiomatic way of expressing it,

or "...***causes***...", as James K has already pointed out in his comment.

Comment: I would say "... creates ...".

Answer (score 1):

You could say that it "invites trouble", or that "the medicine is worse than the cure".

Answer (score 1):

It could be said that *"this solution is going to **open a Pandora's box**"*.

Source: [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open%20a%20Pandora%27s%20box).

Example:

> Money brings us happiness, but sometimes it just opens a Pandora's box.